# TestFlight - Can I upload new version to TestFlight (say from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1) while 1.0 is still under Prepare for submisson?

Tags: ios, testflight

Here is my scenario:

We recently created a iTunes app record for our new app which is not yet available to public. So, by default iTunes shows an app(**1.0**) with status as 'Prepare for Submission'. (I assume we can change this default version number from v**1.0** to v**1.0.0** on the app record. but for clarity I am leaving it as default in my below explanation)

Now, I uploaded my first build with v**1.0.0(0)** to TestFlight and after 4 revisions/build uploads, I made the build v**1.0.0(4)** available for external testers. Now we got few bugs from the external testers and fixed them. Since we did the bug fixes, I want to change the version to v**1.0.1(0)** in TestFlight. Below are my questions struggling to find an answer for:

1) Since the app is not yet released and the default app record version is still v**1.0**, ﻿can I still upload a new version i.e. v**1.0.1(0)** on TestFlight ? 
   a) If I can do the above point(1), will it go through the beta review process again (or) will it simply process and appears on iTunes ? 
    b) If I can do the above point(1), lets say after 2 revisions again like when version is at v**1.0.3(0)**, can I finally push this build to the AppStore as my first release....I mean will it override the default version v**1.0** to v**1.0.3** ?

2) If I cannot achieve the above point(1), then what would be the other approach?

Please suggest me how to proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, yes you can submit your new version (1.0.1) but it will still have to pass through the apple process to get approved for external test.

`If I can do the above point(1), lets say after 2 revisions again like when version is at v1.0.3(0), can I finally push this build to the AppStore as my first release....I mean will it override the default version v1.0 to v1.0.3 ?`

Yes, when you publish your app, you can specify the version displayed in the store so you can display v1.0!

Every time you want to make a new build available to your external tester, Apple need to approve it!

Comment: Thank you Charles...Just to confirm one more thing so it seems like the TestFlight versions doesn't need to be aligned with the  App Record/Store versions right ?.. i.e. In TestFlight I can go starting from v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.2.4, v2.0.2 so on and I can finally decide to push the TestFlight build v2.0.2 to App Store with v1.0.0...

Comment: Thanks Charles, going to do this tomorrow on our TestFlight...I will update the ticket once its successful.

Comment: No still waiting on QA..One more question, what happens to the TestFlight versions after I push to the AppStore...Will they disappear (or) should I continue my next TestFlight build from the version where I left (like for example v2.0.2)

Comment: No they will still be available on testflight